# graphql subscribtions send numberIncremented":null but it must be a number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, graphql, frontend

Help with graphql-subscribtions. I'm writing code on the server that increments a number every second. This number must be sent to the client every time it is changed. It changes on the server. And the client receives this `{"data":{"numberIncremented":null}}`. Why `numberIncremented` is `null`?

Server code: [Server code](https://github.com/nikitazapekin/graphql-server-for-3d-restaurant), Client code: [Client code](https://github.com/nikitazapekin/Restaurant-monitoring-React-and-Three.js-app)

There may be a problem with the rendering of the component

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thank you